# Rspec fails because too few arguments when rescuing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tiny-tds

In a system spec, I'm trying to test the correct handling of a database timeout. When that happens a new `TinyTds::Error` is raised.

Here my controller (`EMData` handles the DB connection)

```
class Json::ChartController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from TinyTds::Error, with: :connection_timed_out

  def index
    data = EMData.call(params) 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: data }
    end
  end


  def connection_timed_out(_error)
    format.json { head :request_timeout }
  end
end
```

Here my spec

```
context 'when the SQL Server connection times out' do
  let(:data_class) { class_spy('EMData').as_stubbed_const }

    it 'a feedback message is displayed' do
      allow(data_class).to receive(:call).and_raise(TinyTds::Error.new('message'))
      ...
      SUBMIT FORM VIA JS
      ...
      expect(page).to have_content("Some Content")
      end
```

The spec seems pretty straightforward to me. However, when I run it , I get

> Rack app error handling request { GET /json/chart/ }
>
> ## /app/controllers/json/chart_controller.rb:24:in `format' ....
>
> Failure/Error: format.json { head :request_timeout }
>
> ```
>  ArgumentError:
>    too few arguments
> ```

Am I misisng anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `respond_to do |format|` in `connection_timed_out(_error)`. It should be like:

```rb
def connection_timed_out(_error)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { head :request_timeout }
  end
end
```